# How to scale an entire website proportionally?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I found this blog post with a neat way of scaling a whole website up proportionally:

https://northstreetcreative.com/notes/full-screen-website-zoom-using-css-transform-and-jquery/

Here's the key code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

 nsZoomZoom(); 

 $( window ).resize(function() { 
   nsZoomZoom();
 });


 function nsZoomZoom() {
    htmlWidth = $('html').innerWidth();
    bodyWidth = 1000;

    if (htmlWidth < bodyWidth)
       scale = 1
    else {
       scale = htmlWidth / bodyWidth; 
    }

    // Req for IE9
    $("body").css('-ms-transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')');
    $("body").css('transform', 'scale(' + scale + ')');
 } 

});
```

The problem is this no longer works in Safari or Chrome.

Does anybody know a fix that will work in 2018?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `-ms-transform` is not needed. jQuery should handle that out of the box by simply using `'transform'`

Comment: @Roko C. Buljan  Thanks.  Do you have any suggestion what to do about Chrome and Safari?

Comment: Can you post a fiddle or example? Not enough info here

Comment: https://codepen.io/skladany/pen/KrjRQE

Comment: Did Safari/Chrome turn off some functionality for (auto)scaling recently?

Comment: I've tried using matrix rather than just scale, but as soon as I add some translation other than 0, it doesn't work.  I tried both with a variable and hard coded.  E.g., $("body").css('transform', 'matrix(' + scale + ', 0, 0, ' + scale + ', 0, 200px)');